# Example on transferring variable values between android activities

Tags: java, android, variables, android-activity

I have 2 variables in lets say class "first" and I want these values in class "second" to do some task. 
What could be the simplest way. 
As I am working on android development the 2 variables values are edittext values entered by the user

Comment: normal Java classes and Android Activities have different context/uses.. Please clarify what exactly you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Either you can put them in second class's `constructor` or make them `public static` so that using class name you can access them..

Answer (score 1):

Using Static it will be shared by all threads. Better to make private and provide the getter and setter method, hence you can access the value by getter method.

Answer (score 1):

In the `first` class, you can do something like this,

```
name_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameText);
String name = name_text.getText().toString();
    Intent intent = new Intent(first.this, Second.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);         
    intent.putExtra("name",name);
    startActivity(intent);
```

and in the `Second` class, you can do something like this,

```
        Intent i = this.getIntent();
String name = i.getStringExtra("name");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean first and Second are Activities then you can user putExtra concept.

**FirstActivity.java**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("var1", editText1.getText().toString());
intent.putExtra("var2", editText2.getText().toString());
startActivity(intent);
```

**SecondActivity.java**

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if (bundle != null) {
    String txtOne = bundle.getString("var1");
    String txtTwo = bundle.getString("var2");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `Intent` to navigate from `Activity1` to `Activity2`, make use of `Intent.putExtra("key", "Value")`

Comment: @user1910290 do u find the solution?